# adsbygoogle.js refuses to load

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

*Note:

I'm not sure whether this is the correct category for the question, if not please tell me.

I have been using Adsense for a while right now and i'm unable to load adsbygoogle.js for unknown reason.

Check the following link: http://syriantc.com, i have three ads in the website which are not loading due to `NOT FOUND 404` error.

This error is only happening my various PCs/Mobiles here where i live (Germany) and in Turkey, BUT i have friends whose PCs are able to reach the link.

Conclusion: Link isn't reachable from my side, and from other people, while it's reachable from other people having the same connection as me, living in the same place as me.

The Ads are not loading for 3 days, and it's pretty much harmful for me and my earnings.

Comment: Any ad blocking extension? Try on incognito.

Comment: All disabled, already checked for this. I have the following error displayed: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED